# 301 variable URL redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm unable to do a 301 redirect rule for a website I'm redoing. This is what the redirection must do:

Original:

```
domain.com/blog/4-blog/49-name-of-post
```

New:

```
domain.com/name-of-post/
```

The `49-` depends on post, meaning is different in all posts, but always 2 digits followed by `-`.

So 2 directories now disappear, also 3 first characters of the page name and the final slash.

Any ideas to accomplish that without doing all redirects by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/[^/]+/[0-9]+-([^/]+)$ /$1/
```

Comment: Not tried yet, but... seems like something is missing. The numeric rule is for 1 digit, right? It must be 2 digit. Maybe something like this?
**RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/[^/]+/[0-9]+[0-9]+-([^/]+)$ /$1/**
Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @VictorCasado "It must be 2 digit" - The `[0-9]+` regex (specifically the `+`) in the above matches **1 or more** digits.